# Converting float3[] from GLSL to Metal

Tags: c++, glsl, metal

How to convert this:

```
const float3 GDFVectors[19] = float3[](
                                   normalize(float3(1, 0, 0)),
                                   normalize(float3(0, 1, 0)),
                                   normalize(float3(0, 0, 1)),

                                   normalize(float3(1, 1, 1 )),
                                   normalize(float3(-1, 1, 1)),
                                   normalize(float3(1, -1, 1)),
                                   normalize(float3(1, 1, -1)),

                                   normalize(float3(0, 1, PHI+1)),
                                   normalize(float3(0, -1, PHI+1)),
                                   normalize(float3(PHI+1, 0, 1)),
                                   normalize(float3(-PHI-1, 0, 1)),
                                   normalize(float3(1, PHI+1, 0)),
                                   normalize(float3(-1, PHI+1, 0)),

                                   normalize(float3(0, PHI, 1)),
                                   normalize(float3(0, -PHI, 1)),
                                   normalize(float3(1, 0, PHI)),
                                   normalize(float3(-1, 0, PHI)),
                                   normalize(float3(PHI, 1, 0)),
                                   normalize(float3(-PHI, 1, 0))
                                   );
```

into `Metal`(or C++)? With the code above I got some errors:

> Global variable must have a constant address space qualifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Metal, you need to qualify the array as being in the `constant` address space in addition to qualifying it as `const`. I'd write this as:

```
constant const float3 GDFVectors[] = {
    normalize(float3(1, 0, 0)),
    // ...
    normalize(float3(-PHI, 1, 0))
};
```

Comment: Wow, this `Metal` really humble me a lot. Why `{ ... }` is used rather than `[ ... ]`? Isn't that an `array`?

Comment: I've only ever used braces for aggregate initialization in C++/Metal. I don't recognize the syntax you're using in the question.